# When does Perl ref($something) return "ARRAY(0x913310)"?

Tags: arrays, perl, ref

I have some complex Perl code that tests the value of `$val = ref($something)`. Unfortunately my code fails, because there is a situation where `$val` is `"ARRAY(0x913310)"` and not `"ARRAY"` (according to the Perl debugger).

Reading the documentation of `ref()`, such a value is not listed as one of the possible return values. Also, when trying to reproduce interactively in the debugger, I only see valid return values.

Could this be a bug in the Perl base?
I'm using Perl 5.10.0 from SLES 11 SP 4 on x86_64...

Comment: Did you make a call like `bless $obj,$val` somewhere where you meant to say `bless $obj,ref($val)` ?

Comment: Perl 5.10.0 [has been around for almost ten years](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhist.html) and there has been one minor release 5.10.1 in 2009. It's quite unlikely that something like this is a bug in Perl itself. It's way more likely you made a convoluted mistake. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `$something` is an object of class `ARRAY(0x913310)`.

```
$ perl -E'
   my $class = "".[];
   say $class;
   my $o = bless({}, $class);
   say ref($o);
'
ARRAY(0x115e360)
ARRAY(0x115e360)
```

Comment: I found the problem: Actually some subroutine was returning an array reference, and the `ref()` function was not applied to that return value before being checked for individual cases. *mea culpa!*, sorry!